# XSLT Tokenize Base-URI, Select Match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the file c:/users/ted9876/docs/foo.xml

Using XSLT 2.0, I'd like to grab the value of ted* from this file path. What would be the best way to achieve this?

I tried using using the below in a stylesheet that was applied to foo.xml;

```
<xsl:value-of select="matches(tokenize(base-uri(),'/'), 'ted.*')" />
```

but, it's returning an error.

Comment: Why don't you go for a substring function?

Comment: Or `starts-with`. Like: `tokenize(base-uri(),'/')[starts-with(.,'ted')]` (you could still use `matches()`, just put it in the predicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Haley answered this in a comment above:

Or starts-with. Like: `tokenize(base-uri(),'/')[starts-with(.,'ted')]` (you could still use `matches()`, just put it in the predicate)